# Does post-workout cold immersion dampen strength as well as hypertrophic gains?

Tags: strength, muscle-gain, hypertrophy, cold, strength-gain

Andrew Hibernian has discussed research suggesting that hypertrophic gains are lost when one undergoes immersive cold exposure within 6 hours after training.

I’m wondering if this six hour window is a tipping point threshold or if it is more of a dose-proportional effect, in that 3 hours would forego less gains than 2 hours, which would in turn forego less training gains than 1, which would forego less than 0.5, etc, and six is simply where it flattens or plateaus. Is there any data which addresses this?

And as with the titular point, does this effect apply to both strength gains as well as hypertrophy gains that would normally result from a training session?

Comment: If I remember right, Huberman said 6 hours because the studies related to it only went up to 6 hours.  It could be as high as 48 hours but it hasn't been studied so we don't know. One would *assume* it's dose-proportional because it inhibits MPS, but if you've waited 24 hours then your body has already made most of the gains it was going to from your last training session. Cold Water isn't going to remove muscle mass, only prevent adding more.